# Capacitor js Camera plugin error Out of memory in Android

Tags: android, image, camera, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

In my Ionic 5 app, I am using [@capacitor/camera](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v3/apis/camera) plugin. Following in the code.

```
let camOption: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 100,
  resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
  source: CameraSource.Photos
}

try {
  const result = await Camera.getPhoto(camOption);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
}
```

When selecting a large image of a size of more than 10MB, I am getting the error `{"message":"Out of memory"}` after few seconds of screen freeze. I see other Out of memory errors reported by users but not sure how to fix this scenario.

Comment: quality 100 and Base64 generates a huge string

Comment: I tried with reduced quality as well and getting the error. In the new Samsung S21 model, this error is even coming for 5MB images with 90 as quality. The phone can take images with size 16MB.

Answer (score 0):

[Working with large files may require you to add android:largeHeap="true" to the  tag in AndroidManifest.xml.](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem#android)

Try to add `android:largeHeat="true"` so you Androidanifest.xml shoul look like

[image]